# How to merge 2 arrays in Angular templates

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have a form directive in angular for displaying errors that looks like this:

```
<form-error errors="form.errors.some-array"></form>
```

The problem is that my *form.erros* object contains 2 arrays full of error messages than must be displayed, *form.errors.arrayOne* and *form.errors.arrayTwo*. How can I display the errors in both arrays?

Is there a way to display both arrays using the same directive? 
Something like this:

```
<form-error errors="form.errors.arrayOne mergeSyntax form.errors.arrayTwo"></form>
```

Is it ok to solve the problem using 2 directives?

```
<form-error errors="form.errors.arrayOne"></form>
<form-error errors="form.errors.arrayTwo"></form>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @JBNizet I was thinks of something more simple like merging the arrays in the template code.

Comment: That is hard to do because you need to always return the same array at each digest loop if the two inputs contain the same elements, otherwise you'll run into an infinite digest loop error. Just add a third array to form.errors, and make sure that every time you modify arrayOne or arrayTwo, this third array is modified to, so that it always contains the concatenation of the two original arrays. See http://plnkr.co/edit/bworexwRcaPzDAJNdr9S?p=preview for an example.